# Intercepting Tab key press to manage focus switching manually

Tags: qt, event-handling, qt4, qt5, keyevent

I want to intercept <kbd>Tab</kbd> key press in my main window to prevent Qt from switching focus. Here's what I've tried so far:

```cpp
bool CMainWindow::event(QEvent * e)
{
    if (e && e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent * keyEvent = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(e);
        if (keyEvent && keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
            return true;
    }
    return QMainWindow::event(e);
}
```

This doesn't work, `event` isn't called when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. How to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reimplementing `virtual bool QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * e)` and pasting the code from my question there works.

Answer (score 13):

The most elegant way I found to avoid focus change is to reimplement in your class derived from QWidget the method `bool focusNextPrevChild(bool next)` and simply return `FALSE`. In case you want to allow it, return `TRUE`.

Like other keys you get now also the key `Qt::Key_Tab` in `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve by using  `setFocusPolicy( Qt::NoFocus)` property of QWidget. You can set Focus policy on widget which doesn't require tab focus. I think the reason why event handler is not calling, because Tab is managed by Qt framework internally. Please see `QWidget::setTabOrder` API, which is static.

Comment: I don't need to fully disable focus switch, just want to do it my way. Tried focus policy - that wasn't enough. But I didn't know about `QWidget::setTabOrder`, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to install an event filter on your main window in order to receive the events. You can use [installEventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) method for this.
Another option is to override the [keyPressEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) method to handle the key presses.

Comment: `keyPressEvent` isn't being called either for Tab key. And neither does `eventFilter`.

Comment: Can you add the code where how you installed the event filter / overridden the keyPressEvent method?

Comment: It's exactly the same, just different method names. And I have checked that my overriden methods are being called when I press keys other than Tab.

Comment: For the keyPressEvent way... The signature of the overridden method is exactly "void CMainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)"?

Comment: For the event way... Did you add the installEventFilter(this) line to the constructor of your CMainWindow class?

Comment: Of course. Like I said, both methods are being called for other, "normal" keys. How could they if I made a mistake in the method's signature. It won't take you longer than 5 minutes to create a test app and confirm neither works for Tab.

Comment: Found a solution, check my answer if interested.

Comment: Sorry, I misread "event isn't called when I press Tab" as function not called at all... my bad. It is actually not working for me as well. I can catch the event when I'm changing from Qt::KeyPress to Qt::KeyRelease, but this is obviously too late for you. Maybe you want to try to override the focusOutEvent (or similar methods) and simply do nothing there?